# What type of analysis for sequential data can I use to identify patterns in collaborative activities

Tags: time-series, arima, sequential-analysis, sequential-pattern-mining

I have a data set, which is collected every 5 second for a total of one hour using a special type of wearable device. Each data point is the amount of verbal participation ratio (measured as percent) of each group member in the same group (4 members in total).

Now the two research questions I want to answer are: 1. What is the pattern of each group members' verbal participation behavior over the course of one hour. 2. Is the pattern of a member's participation data collected in the initial stage of the session predictable of the pattern in the later stage of the session? (similar to time-series forecast etc). 
*Note:* By **"pattern"** I mean: The change/shift of each team member's participation ratio from the beginning to the end of the session.
I thought about using time series analysis, but I'm new to time series. Can you give me some suggestions on which type of analysis to use?  Thank you all.